# Как передать проект заказчику?

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegram-bot, mongodb, telegram

предположим у меня есть проект телеграмм бота на Node.js
Как лучше его отправить?
Как быть с правами на бота?
Заказчик должен сам регистрировать бота и вставлять свой токен?
Где и как заказчик должен его запустить?
Расскажите зелёному, как вы это делаете? Буду очень признателен, спасибо)

Comment: Зависит от Ваших договоренностей с заказчиком. Для деплоя обычно достаточно в ридми описать порядок деплоя и "отдать" репозиторий заказчику. Токен можно вставить через переменную окружения. Если заказчик не разбирается в деплое, вероятно, это придется делать Вам. Вы деплоите Ваш код на сервер и вносите токен.

Comment: Понял, спасибо)