# Бот должен отправить сообщение из беседы пользователю, как это сделать?

Tags: telegram-bot, бот, telegram

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Нужно написать бота, который собирает информацию о «заказе», отправляет одним сообщением всю информацию в группу с админами, прикрепляя кнопки с вариантами ответа админов (на фото реализация), а админы отправляют путём этих кнопок ответ обратно пользователю.

Как организовать ответ админов пользователю?
При нажатии на кнопку, текст с кнопки должен отправиться пользователю через бота.

Попробовала через forward.message, все работает только для меня (так как я являюсь админом беседы). Если приходят данные с другого телеграмм-аккаунта, при нажатии на кнопку в беседе админов мною ответ приходит не другому пользователю, а мне

Добавила фрагмент обработки сообщения, если приходит ссылка. На питоне пишу впервые, так что прошу строго не судить, стараюсь собирать код с помощью разных подсказок форумов и гитхаба :D

Запуталась, прошу помочь :(
Спасибо!

То есть бот работает так: пользователь ведет с ботом диалог, собирается информация, которая отправляется ботом в беседу с админами, затем админы нажимают на кнопку и пользователю должен вернуть их ответ. То есть админы делают свайп по экрану, выделяя сообщение для ответа и нажимают кнопку и пользователь, чей ник написан в выделенном сообщении, должен получить ответ

```py
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def answer(message):
    if 'https://steam' in message.text:
        information = 'Тут собирается информация от пользователя'
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
        item_1 = types.KeyboardButton('Первая кнопка')
        markup.add(item_1)
        bot.send_message('id беседы с админами', information, reply_markup=markup)

        user_ID = message.from_user.id
        if message.caption is not None and "Первая кнопка" in message.caption.lower():
            bot.forward_message(user_ID, -1001728991819, message.message.id) # в этой части, мне кажется, что-то не то
    
    elif message.text == 'Скин отправлен, принимай трейд':
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Скин отправлен, принимай трейд')
```

Comment: На чем пишите? И код в студию

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: @oleksandrigo отредактировала вопрос, добавила скриншоты кода, пишу на Питоне

Comment: Здесь не приветствуются скриншоты кода, запихните код в три апострофа которые на Ё, по типу три апострофа ->  перенос строки -> КОД -> перенос строки -> три апострофа. Это раз. А еще прошу подробно обьяснить как вы хотите это видеть, по действиям, типа - нажал сюда произошло то-то, потом то-то.

Comment: Вообще по нормальному сюда нужен минимальный код, при котором можно воспроизвести то что происходит у вас.

Comment: Дальше, как происходит взаимодействие бот - юзер? Где находиться бот? Это чистое ЛС или бот состоит в группе?

Comment: @oleksandrigo добавила код, в комментарии указала дальнейшую работу бота

Comment: О. Вот теперь я начал понимать что вы хотите. Но как я понимаю у вас не получиться делая свап сообщения нажать на кнопку. Это как две разные концепции. 1) Это в админгруппу попадает инфа с инлайн кнопками, после админ жамкает кнопку и юзеру отправляется сообщение. 2) Это когда админ получает просто месседж(без кнопок) и свайпая его пишет руками некий текст и отправляет -> бот видит это и пересылает обратно юзеру. Вопрос. Что вам нужнее кастомные ответы юзеру или простота в виде инлайн кнопок?

Comment: @oleksandrigo свайпая, получается нажамать на кнопку. У меня ReplyKeyboard, они читаются как обычный текст в сообщении. Когда я сама тестирую бота и нажимаю на кнопки, все работает, но если другой пользователь общается с ботом, присылается его информация, я отвечаю кнопкой, то ответ снова приходит мне… что сделать, чтобы ответ уходил по его ID :D

Comment: Хмм. Протестил, реально можно после свайпа нажать на кнопку. Но в целом, я рекомендую инлайн-кнопки под самим сообщением. Думаю для реализации будет проще. Но если вы хотите замараться, то можете в сообщение которое идет админам запихнуть айди юзера, а потом при нажатии на кнопку (по факту при отлове сообщения) искать этот айди и по нему делать простой bot.send_message(...) Если же вы не против инлайн кнопок, то завтра могу написать, а то уже лень

Comment: Более того если в беседу с админами придет более одного сообщения то оно будет перекрывать реплай клавиатуру предыдущего. Потому я и настаиваю на инлайн кнопках

Comment: @oleksandrigo можно ли с вами связаться где-то помимо форума? Я изначально хотела делать inline кнопки, но не разобралась, как работает ответ с них, у меня выдавалась ошибка и я решила сделать Reply. Буду очень благодарна, если подскажите, как сделать inline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем вот.

```
from telebot import TeleBot, types
from telebot.types import InlineKeyboardMarkup, InlineKeyboardButton
# я отсюда беру токен, не обращай внимания
import config

bot = TeleBot(config.BOT_TOKEN)

# начинаем разговор с ботом
# он просит нас отправить имя и мы регистрируем следующий хендлер/функцию
# которая будет реагировать на сообщение юзера
# в неё передаем обьект месседж(также можно передавать колбек) и название функции
# которая и будет это делать (без вызова, только название)
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message: types.Message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text="Привет, напиши имя")
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, get_name)

# собственно сама функция
# в ней делаем сразу маркап, и в колбек дату передаем такую строку
# type:accept@id:{message.from_user.id} 
# всё что здесь написано мы руками обрабатываем в след хендлере, чтобы
# получит информацию о юзере. 
# разбиваем строку по смыслу собакой @, а по тип-данные разбиваем двоеточием
# accept чуть ниже обьясню, а в айди кидаем айди юзера
# отправляем в чат по айдишнику (само собой у вас другой айди)
# в текст вписываем то что написал юзер, а в reply_markup собственно маркап
def get_name(message: types.Message):
    markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup().add(
        InlineKeyboardButton("Принимай трейд", callback_data=f"type:accept@id:{message.from_user.id}"))
    bot.send_message(chat_id=-614322222, text=f"{message.text}", reply_markup=markup)

# делаем колбек хендлер, с фильтром в виде лямбда функции
# которая берет наш колбек, вытаскивает из неё data (это по факту строка
# которую мы писали в колбек дате при создании кнопки)
# дальше проверяем её на валидность, по факту чтобы начиналась со строки "type:"
# и этот хендлер будет срабатывать исключительно на нашу кнопку
###
# дальше вызываем anwer_calback_query, чтобы пропал значок часов на кнопке
# после проверяем на тип чата, который в принципе можно 
# запихнуть в фильтр хендлера, но в целом неважно
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: call.data.startswith("type:"))
def handle_from_admin(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query_id=call.id)
    
    if call.message.chat.type == "group":
        # вытаскиваем данные а именно, тип ответа, который был нажат
        # (мы не можем получить текст с инлайн кнопки, потому делаем так)
        # и юзер айди
        type_answer = call.data.split("@")[0].split(":")[1]
        user_id = call.data.split("@")[1].split(":")[1]
        # делаем словарь по типу type_answer - ответ,
        # чтобы добавить кнопки создайте новый ключ, и добавьте такой же ключ 
        # при создании инлайн кнопки
        answers = {
            "accept": "Принимай трейд",
        }
        text = answers[type_answer]
        # ну и отправляем уже в лс
        bot.send_message(chat_id=user_id, text=text)


bot.infinity_polling(skip_pending=True)
```

Собственно где-то вот так. Единственное я не знаю насколько много данных вы хотите вытащить из юзера, если немного то все их можно запихать в колбек дату, если много то наверное лучше юзать какой-нибудь FSM для телебота. Я не очень люблю телебот, потому советую айограм, в нем есть несколько хороших фич, для работы с колбеками да и вообще с данными.

UPD.
Пример добавления кнопки

```
def get_name(message: types.Message):
    markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup().add(
        InlineKeyboardButton("Принимай трейд", callback_data=f"type:accept@id:{message.from_user.id}")).add(
        InlineKeyboardButton("У тебя мало кейсов", callback_data=f"type:not_enough_cases@id:{message.from_user.id}"))
    bot.send_message(chat_id=-614322222, text=f"{message.text}", reply_markup=markup)

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: call.data.startswith("type:"))
def handle_from_admin(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query_id=call.id)

    if call.message.chat.type == "group":
        type_answer = call.data.split("@")[0].split(":")[1]
        user_id = call.data.split("@")[1].split(":")[1]
        answers = {
            "accept": "Принимай трейд",
            "not_enough_cases": "Мало кейсов"
        }
        text = answers[type_answer]
        bot.send_message(chat_id=user_id, text=text)
```

Comment: спасибо огромное! Сижу разбираюсь, не совсем пока понимаю, откуда у нас появилось слово "group" и не поняла пока сточки с type_answer и user_id... То есть как и что именно нужно менять, чтобы сделать для других кнопок...

Comment: Ну смотри, group это тип чата [ссылка](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI#how-can-i-distinguish-a-user-and-a-groupchat-in-messagechat). type_answer и user_id это лично наш способ маркировать данные в строке. Можно написать что угодно. К примеру в type_answer мы просто разбиваем строку `f"type:accept@id:{message.from_user.id}"` по @ и получаем массив из двух элементов `[type:accept, id:{message.from_user.id}]` только айдишник уже будет конкретным. Далее берем 0-ой (1 -ый) элемент массива `type:accept` и снова разбиваем его, но уже по `:` и берем 1-ый (2-ой) элемент, это тип ответа

Comment: Вот это самое accept, это способ понять какая конкретно кнопка нажата. Далее мы вставляем его в словарь и сразу понимаем какое-сообщение отправить юзеру. Если  вы хотите сделать больше кнопок вам нужно, 1) добавить ключ-значение в answers где ключ это type_answer, а значение строка которая отправиться юзеру. 2) сделать markup.add(...) и по аналогии делаете вторую кнопку, меняете текст кнопки и то что стоит после type: . К примеру markup.add(InlineKeyboardButton("У тебя мало кейсов", callback_data=f"type:not_enough_cases@id:{message.from_user.id}")) ну и этот not_enough_cases в вставляй словарь

Comment: как создать кнопку поняла, да, но в голове пока отказывается укладываться именно обработка, чтобы получался другой ответ при нажатии на вторую, например, кнопку. У меня ответ тот же отправляется, видимо, не то меняю. Нам нужно добавлять elif в handle_from_admin или я уже совсем запуталась? 
И огромное Вам спасибо за такие подробные ответы!

Comment: Вы в answers добавили ответ?

Comment: Гляньте, я обновил ответ, в конце

Comment: Все было гениально просто, а я мудрила, пытаясь поменять везде все :D Спасибо Вам невероятно огромное!!! Может Вы можете посоветовать что-то для изучения, чтобы самостоятельно совершенствовать знания в этой сфере? Сейчас учусь делать ботов по форумам, примерам и подобиям... Мало ли есть какие-то источники, о которых мне просто еще неизвестно, очень хочу умнеть в этой области :D

Comment: Ха, я учусь тут на стеке, постоянно какие-нибудь вопросы, которые я плохо понимаю, вот и разбираюсь, лезу в документацию или ещё куда. Никакой литературы, я не знаю по нему. Думаю достаточно написать в гугле aiogram и что-то полезное найдётся. Ну и если ответ вам подходит можете закрывать вопрос нажав на галочку слева от ответа.

Comment: Спасибо большое Вам!

Comment: Чтобы не создавать новый вопрос, спрошу на всякий случай тут сначала. Знаете ли Вы, как запускают чаще всего ботов? Знаю, что нужны сервера, но неужели фрилансеры, создавая для заказчиков новых ботов, каждый раз отдают бота с сервером и подпиской на него?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1140778/Как-передать-проект-заказчику думаю примерно так